Integrating GNN with PPO for Robot Control in Gymnasium's Ant-v4
I'm exploring the integration of Graph Neural Networks (GNNs) and Reinforcement Learning (RL) using stable_baselines3 and Gymnasium, specifically for robot control inspired by the approach in NerveNet. My project involves the Ant-v4 environment, where I'm attempting to model the environment as a graph, with each node representing a hinge in the robot's structure.
I've opted to use the Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) algorithm to optimize the RL process. Despite several weeks of effort, I've struggled to successfully merge these concepts. The core challenge seems to be in the effective integration of the graph-based model with the RL algorithm to enhance learning.
Could anyone provide insights or share experiences on:

Best practices for modeling physical environments (like the Ant robot) as graphs for use in GNNs?

Tips on integrating these graph representations with PPO or other RL algorithms effectively?

Guidance or references to similar projects?


from typing import Callable, Dict, List, Optional, Tuple, Type, Union

from torch_geometric.nn import GATv2Conv

from gymnasium import spaces

import gymnasium as gym

from gymnasium import ActionWrapper, ObservationWrapper, RewardWrapper, Wrapper

import torch as th

from torch import nn

from torch_geometric.data import Data

from stable_baselines3 import PPO

from stable_baselines3.common.policies import ActorCriticPolicy

import torch.nn.functional as F

import numpy as np

from torch.distributions import Normal

edge_index = th.tensor([[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 5], [0, 7], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=th.long).t().contiguous()

class GATv2ConvWrapper(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, edge_index):
        super(GATv2ConvWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.conv = GATv2Conv(in_channels, out_channels)
        self.edge_index = edge_index  # Storing edge_index as an attribute

    def forward(self, x):
        # Use the stored edge_index for the graph convolution
        return self.conv(x, self.edge_index)


class CustomNetwork(nn.Module):
    

    def __init__(
        self,
        feature_dim: int = 11,
        last_layer_dim_pi: int = 64,
        last_layer_dim_vf: int = 64,
    ):
        super().__init__()

        # IMPORTANT:
        # Save output dimensions, used to create the distributions
        self.latent_dim_pi = last_layer_dim_pi
        self.latent_dim_vf = last_layer_dim_vf

        # Policy Network
         
        self.policy_net = nn.Sequential(
            GATv2ConvWrapper(feature_dim, last_layer_dim_pi, edge_index), 
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            GATv2ConvWrapper(last_layer_dim_pi, last_layer_dim_pi, edge_index), 
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
        )

        # Value network components
        self.value_net = nn.Sequential(
            GATv2ConvWrapper(feature_dim, last_layer_dim_pi, edge_index),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            GATv2ConvWrapper(last_layer_dim_pi, last_layer_dim_pi, edge_index), 
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
        )
        # Log Probs
        self.log_std = nn.Parameter(th.zeros(1, 8))  # Log standard deviations for actions

        


    def forward(self, features):
        # Compute policy (mean action values) and sample actions
        actions = self.forward_actor(features).mean(dim=1)
        values =  self.forward_critic(features).mean(dim=1)
        print("ACtions Mean: ", actions)
        return actions, values

    def forward_actor(self, features: Data):
        print("Actore giren:", features)
        x, edge_index = features.x, features.edge_index
        return self.policy_net(x)

    def forward_critic(self, features: Data):
        print("Critice giren:", features)
        x, edge_index = features.x, features.edge_index
        return self.value_net(x)
    
    def model_ant_as_graph(state: th.Tensor) -> Data:
        # Check if state is a batch of observations
        if state.dim() == 2:
            state = state[0]  # Take the first observation in the batch

        node_indices = {
            'torso': slice(0, 5),
            'hip_1': slice(5, 6), 'ankle_1': slice(6, 7),
            'hip_2': slice(7, 8), 'ankle_2': slice(8, 9),
            'hip_3': slice(9, 10), 'ankle_3': slice(10, 11),
            'hip_4': slice(11, 12), 'ankle_4': slice(12, 13),
        }
        velocity_indices = {
            'torso': slice(13, 19),
            'hip_1': slice(19, 20), 'ankle_1': slice(20, 21),
            'hip_2': slice(21, 22), 'ankle_2': slice(22, 23),
            'hip_3': slice(23, 24), 'ankle_3': slice(24, 25),
            'hip_4': slice(25, 26), 'ankle_4': slice(26, 27),
        }
                
        node_features = []
        for key in node_indices.keys():
            combined_features = th.cat((state[node_indices[key]], state[velocity_indices[key]]))
            padded_features = F.pad(combined_features, (0, 11 - combined_features.size(0)), "constant", 0)
            node_features.append(padded_features)
        
        node_features_tensor = th.stack(node_features).float()
        graph = Data(x=node_features_tensor, edge_index=edge_index, num_nodes=9)
        return graph    

   


    
class CustomActorCriticPolicy(ActorCriticPolicy):
    def __init__(
        self,
        observation_space: spaces.Space,
        action_space: spaces.Space,
        lr_schedule: Callable[[float], float],
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        kwargs["ortho_init"] = False
        super().__init__(
            observation_space,
            action_space,
            lr_schedule,
            # Pass remaining arguments to base class
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )

    # In the forward method of your policy:
    def forward(self, obs):
        
        graph_data = model_ant_as_graph(obs)  # Convert observations to graph data here
        actions, values = self.mlp_extractor(graph_data)
        print("Actions:", actions)
        
        return actions, values

    def _build_mlp_extractor(self) -> None:
        self.mlp_extractor = CustomNetwork(11)
env = gym.make("Ant-v4")
model = PPO(CustomActorCriticPolicy, env, verbose=1)
print(model.policy)

Output of the print statement:
CustomActorCriticPolicy(
  (features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (pi_features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (vf_features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (mlp_extractor): CustomNetwork(
    (policy_net): Sequential(
      (0): GATv2ConvWrapper(
        (conv): GATv2Conv(11, 64, heads=1)
      )
      (1): BatchNorm1d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): GATv2ConvWrapper(
        (conv): GATv2Conv(64, 64, heads=1)
      )
      (3): BatchNorm1d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (value_net): Sequential(
      (0): GATv2ConvWrapper(
        (conv): GATv2Conv(11, 64, heads=1)
      )
      (1): BatchNorm1d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): GATv2ConvWrapper(
        (conv): GATv2Conv(64, 64, heads=1)
      )
      (3): BatchNorm1d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (action_net): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=8, bias=True)
  (value_net): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=1, bias=True)
)

